# How to reduce the form validation fields in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have a form with 3 input fields. But I want to use the form also for other pages. Therefore I have reduced the form. At the beginning I've defined the view as follows:

View:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="editForm" novalidate>
  <div ng-repeat="elements in form">
    <div class="form-group-sm has-feedback" ng-repeat="el in elements.items" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : hasError(editForm), 'has-success' : hasSuccess(editForm) }">
       <label class="control-label" for="{{el.id}}">{{el.label}}</label>
       <input type="{{el.fieldType}}"
              class="form-control" 
              placeholder="{{el.label}}"  
              name="{{el.name}}" 
              id="{{el.id}}"
              ng-model="selected[el.model]" 
              ng-disabled="{{el.disabled}}"
              ng-pattern="el.pattern" 
              ng-required="{{el.required}}"
       />
       <p class="help-block" ng-show="editForm.{{el.name}}.$error.required && editForm.{{el.name}}.$touched">Field is required.</p>
       <p class="help-block" ng-show="editForm.{{el.name}}.$error.pattern">Thats the pattern error message.</p>
   </div>
 </div>    
</form>
```

I want to outsource the error messages / validation in a function. The error messages in the p-Tag don't work.

I've tried this in my Ctrl:

```
$scope.hasError = function (form) {
   return form.Firstname.$invalid && form.Firstname.$dirty;
}

$scope.hasSuccess = function (form) {
   return form.Firstname.$valid;
}
```

That is only for the inputfield Firstname. But how can I define this dynamically for all fields (firstname, lastname, age)?

Answer (score 1):

Pass dynamic field name into function:

```
ng-class="{ 'has-error' : hasError(editForm, el.name), 'has-success' : hasSuccess(editForm, el.name) }"
```

and in controller use bracket notation to access variable ngModelController:

```
$scope.hasError = function (form, name) {
   return form[name].$invalid && form[name].$dirty;
};

$scope.hasSuccess = function (form, name) {
   return form[name].$valid;
};
```

Comment: Thx for the solution but is it possible to improve the code in ngShow? I mean to outsource in a function or directive or similar??

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <p class="help-block" ng-show="editForm[el.name].$error.required && editForm[el.name].$touched">Field is required.</p>
 <p class="help-block" ng-show="editForm[el.name].$error.pattern">Thats the pattern error message.</p>
```

Comment: is it possible to outsource the code in ngShow in a function? What is best practice for this kind of code?

Comment: checkout ngMessages in angularjs
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages